# Alguém pode me ajudar a encontrar o que está causando um erro de compilação no código?

Tags: c

Fui resolver o exercício 1022 do UriOnlineJudge e recebi um compilation error, porém o código funciona perfeitamente no Code::Blocks. Por favor, me informe qual o erro.
[Link do problema.](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1022)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void simplificacao(int *a, int *b){
    for(int j=*b;j>0;j--){
        if(*a%j==0 && *b%j==0){
            *a/=j;
            *b/=j;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    int x, N1, D1, N2, D2, i, N3, D3;
    char t1, op, t2;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    for(i=0;i<x;i++){
        scanf("%d %c %d %c %d %c %d", &N1, &t1, &D1, &op, &N2, &t2, &D2);
        if(op == '+'){
            N3 = (N1*D2 + N2*D1);
            D3 = (D1*D2);
            printf("%d/%d = ", N3, D3);
            simplificacao(&N3,  &D3);
            printf("%d/%d\n", N3, D3);
        }
        else if(op == '-'){
            N3 = (N1*D2 - N2*D1);
            D3 = (D1*D2);
            printf("%d/%d = ", N3, D3);
            simplificacao(&N3, &D3);
            printf("%d/%d\n", N3, D3);
        }
        else if(op == '*'){
            N3 = (N1*N2);
            D3 = (D1*D2);
            printf("%d/%d = ", N3, D3);
            simplificacao(&N3, &D3);
            printf("%d/%d\n", N3, D3);
        }
        else if(op == '/'){
            N3 = (N1*D2);
            D3 = (N2*D1);
            printf("%d/%d = ", N3, D3);
            simplificacao(&N3, &D3);
            printf("%d/%d\n", N3, D3);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Se estás a usar o compilador `gcc` com o CodeBlocks, experimenta os parametros `gcc -std=c89 -pedantic ...` para teres o mesmo comportamento que no online judge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O teu código está correcto para versões recentes de C, desde C99.

Em C89 (aparentemente o C que é usado no site em questão), não é possível usar a declaração de variaveis dentro do `for`

```
// válido em C99, C11, C17
for(int j=*b;j>0;j--){
    // ...
}
```

Muda o `j` para fora do `for` e acrescenta um bloco desassociado se pretenderes manter o *scope* limitado

```
// válido em C89 (C90), C99, C11, C17
{
    int j;
    for(j = *b; j > 0; j--) {
        // ...
    }
}
```